# get result same time in multiple table

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have table like below and I try to find how to 
get the result is article id array or article rows,
sametimes match tag 'hiphop','rock','single' in `ArticleTag0` and `ArticleTag1` table.

Right now I use below code,
get each article id array tagged in different tag type,

e.g if article id rows tagged in Article x Tag0 is [0, 2, 4, 6] and Article x Tag1 is [0, 4, 9],
then compare each array get the number both in above two array get , [0, 4].

I'm wondering is there any better query select them one time?  consider performance

table

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Article"(
    "ArticleId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "PublishDate" timestamp without time zone,
    "Active" bit NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("ArticleId")
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Tag0"(
    "TagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "Name" varchar,
    "Active" bit NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("TagId")
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Tag1"(
    "TagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "Name" varchar,
    "Active" bit NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("TagId")
    );


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "ArticleTag0"(
    "ArticleTagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "ArticleId" integer NOT NULL,
    "TagId" integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ("ArticleId") REFERENCES "Article" ("ArticleId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ("TagId") REFERENCES "Tag0" ("TagId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("ArticleTagId")
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "ArticleTag1"(
    "ArticleTagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "ArticleId" integer NOT NULL,
    "TagId" integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ("ArticleId") REFERENCES "Article" ("ArticleId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ("TagId") REFERENCES "Tag1" ("TagId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("ArticleTagId")
    );
```

code

user input params
inputGenres (Tag0) - [ 'hiphop', 'rock' ]
inputReleaseType (Tag1) - [ 'single' ]

```
    ... 
    // inputGenres
    var inputGenresArticleIdList = [];

    if (inputGenres[0] == 'all') {
      var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Article"';
      var params = [];

      var selectArticle = yield crudDatabase(db,query,params);
      if (typeof selectArticle.error !== 'undefined') {
        response.meta.code = '500';
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectArticle.result.rows.length; i++) {
          inputGenresArticleIdList.push(selectArticle.result.rows[i].ArticleId);
        }
      }
    } else {
      var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT ON ("ArticleId") * FROM "ArticleTag0" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Tag0" ON ("ArticleTag0"."TagId" = "Tag0"."TagId") WHERE "Name" IN (';
      for (var i = 0; i < inputGenres.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
          query += ',';
        }
        query += '$' + (i + 1);
      }
      query += ')';
      var params = inputGenres;

      var selectArticleTag0 = yield crudDatabase(db,query,params);
      if (typeof selectArticleTag0.error !== 'undefined') {
        response.meta.code = '500';
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectArticleTag0.result.rows.length; i++) {
          inputGenresArticleIdList.push(selectArticleTag0.result.rows[i].ArticleId);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(inputGenresArticleIdList);
    // end: inputGenres


    // inputReleaseType
    var inputReleaseTypeArticleIdList = [];

    if (inputReleaseType[0] == 'all') {
      var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Article"';
      var params = [];

      var selectArticle = yield crudDatabase(db,query,params);
      if (typeof selectArticle.error !== 'undefined') {
        response.meta.code = '500';
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectArticle.result.rows.length; i++) {
          inputReleaseTypeArticleIdList.push(selectArticle.result.rows[i].ArticleId);
        }
      }
    } else {
      var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT ON ("ArticleId") * FROM "ArticleTag4" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Tag4" ON ("ArticleTag4"."TagId" = "Tag4"."TagId") WHERE "Name" IN (';
      for (var i = 0; i < inputReleaseType.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
          query += ',';
        }
        query += '$' + (i + 1);
      }
      query += ')';
      var params = inputReleaseType;

      var selectArticleTag4 = yield crudDatabase(db,query,params);
      if (typeof selectArticleTag4.error !== 'undefined') {
        response.meta.code = '500';
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectArticleTag4.result.rows.length; i++) {
          inputReleaseTypeArticleIdList.push(selectArticleTag4.result.rows[i].ArticleId);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(inputReleaseTypeArticleIdList);
    // end: inputReleaseType

    ... then loop each array and compare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's better to do the job with one SQL statement: it is less complicated, it saves roundtrips to the server and back, it makes use of database's algorithms and optimizations.

You can get the result you want using the following statement:

```
select *
from   "Article" a
where  exists (
         select 1
         from   "ArticleTag0" at0,
                "Tag0" t0
         where  at0."ArticleId" = a."ArticleId"
         and    t0."TagId" = at0."TagId" 
         and    t0."Name" in ('hiphop','rock')
       )
and    exists (
         select 1
         from   "ArticleTag1" at1, 
                "Tag1" t1 
         where  at1."ArticleId" = a."ArticleId"
         and    t1."TagId" = at1."TagId" 
         and    t1."Name" in ('single')
       );
```

You still need to change literals (like `'hiphop'`) to bind variables (`$i`), of course. 'All' option for tags can be done by substituting appropriate `exists(...)` block with `true`.

---

But I would suggest a little redesign of your schema. How about representing tags of an article by an array?

```
create table article(
  articleId   serial primary key,
  publishDate timestamp without time zone,
  active      boolean, -- clearer that 'bit'
  genres      text[],  -- array of genre tags
  releases    text[]   -- array of release tags
);
```

Benefits:

1. No need for intermediate tables (like `ArticleTag0`) between articles and tags.
2. Simpler queries.
3. Possibility to use overlap operation of arrays with index support.

Lets insert some values:

```
tags=# insert into article(publishDate,active,genres,releases) values ('2015-09-01',true,'{"hiphop"}','{"single"}');
INSERT 0 1
tags=# insert into article(publishDate,active,genres,releases) values ('2015-10-01',true,'{"rock","blues"}','{"album"}');
INSERT 0 1
tags=# insert into article(publishDate,active,genres,releases) values ('2015-11-01',true,'{"pop"}','{"ep"}');
INSERT 0 1

tags=# select * from article;
 articleid |     publishdate     | active |    genres    | releases 
-----------+---------------------+--------+--------------+----------
         1 | 2015-09-01 00:00:00 | t      | {hiphop}     | {single}
         2 | 2015-10-01 00:00:00 | t      | {rock,blues} | {album}
         3 | 2015-11-01 00:00:00 | t      | {pop}        | {ep}
(3 rows)
```

The query now is as simple and clear as possible (`&&` operator means 'overlaps'):

```
tags=# select * from article where genres && '{"hiphop","rock"}' and releases && '{"single"}';
 articleid |     publishdate     | active |  genres  | releases 
-----------+---------------------+--------+----------+----------
         1 | 2015-09-01 00:00:00 | t      | {hiphop} | {single}
(1 row)
```

Also it simplifies construction of the query text: use `select * from article where genres && $1 and releases && $2;` and generate appropriate strings for `$1` and `$2`.

To speed up the query you can create two GIN indexes which support `&&` operator for arrays:

```
create index on article using gin(genres);
create index on article using gin(releases);
```

Comment: wow Thanks so much for the description and also thanks for the redesign schema :)

Comment: I have question if I follow the redesign schema use array type column. Then if I want to delete all `hiphop` value in genres each array in all article rows (not delete article only delete the specific tag), how to do it?  and the performance good enough than before design?

Comment: `update article set genres = array_remove(genres, 'hiphop') where '{"hiphop"}' <@ genres;`  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html

Comment: This can use the index, so I believe it's okay with performance. Though you should test on your data.